# YouTube Data API v3 check if a Video/Song has explicit lyrics

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So, I am working with the YouTube Data API v3, specifically working on getting data from YouTube Music songs. On YouTube music and the actual youtube player, it tells you whether or not a video has explicit lyrics.

[image: bottom of video player with parental advisory]

I know this data is somewhere but I cannot find anywhere in the API support how to get this information.

I have tried using video.list() and can't find anything that will tell me whether or not the lyrics are explicit. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide a video id example?

Comment: Here's the videoId for Tame Impala - The Less I Know The Better: PvM79DJ2PmM [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvM79DJ2PmM)

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/49004efca4cbf4a453b0839f91c63d3e0146ac60#diff-515c409ddb619da28c52829262e517f3d2ab4910aaa2ab60dd88e9064e0cfd4fR454-R455) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=explicitLyrics&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get the boolean you are looking for in `item["explicitLyrics"]`.

With the video id [`PvM79DJ2PmM`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvM79DJ2PmM) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "PvM79DJ2PmM",
            "explicitLyrics": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems to be inaccurate on some songs. I tried videoID 1UN7uSflwqw and it shows false when it shows on the view page that it has explicit lyrics

Comment: Looks like that only happens when I run my instance of the API. It is more accurate if I use the yt.lemnoslife.com. But this videoID ISEIxaPsp_I doesn't display accurately on either my instance, or on the yt.lemnoslife.com

Comment: Thank you for reporting, my code in theory in case of doubts only returns false negatives and no false positives, so [I precised it](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/278ca22b530a949bd86d93ddb58d3cf7ecc80748) to still not return false positives but less false negatives.